# How to control representation of relation inside a serializer in DRF?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have several serializers with related fields or serializers as fields, but with the default configuration of Django Rest Framework, either everything is dumped, or only the ID, or a URL.

I want to be able to control the verbosity of the representation a bit more:

- sometime I want just the ID or my related field;
- sometime I want the full object dump.
- I may want the ID in ouput, and the dump in output.

Right now I have to serialize everything manually because I can't find a quick and easy way to tell DRF, hey, here just do this.

Is there such a way ?

Comment: As of now you can just specify all fields and exclude them like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27935558/dynamically-exclude-or-include-a-field-in-django-rest-framework-serializer#27936077 whenever needed.

Comment: I don't want to exclude fields, that would end up with {'id': 1}, and for the id part, I just want the id, not the dict around it.

Comment: Unfortunately no inbuilt support for this as far as I know. I usually end up using two serializers when my input takes ids and output needs the whole object dumps. But I guess this can be customized.

Comment: By manually serializing you mean you manually define fields you want to serialize inside a serializer? How do you want it to behave instead, the fields need to be listed somewhere one way or another.

Comment: No I mean defining 2 serializers and calling them manually inside the other serializer.