# User registration with django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am beginning to use the Django Rest Framework and making a user registration process. I have used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23034696/django-rest-framework-user-registration) to create a rudimental version and it works fine, but I get the hashed password back in my response, which I don't want. Tried using `write_only_fields`, but that made no difference.

This is my current serializer:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User(email=validated_data['email'], username=validated_data['username'])
        user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
        user.save()
        return user

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'email', 'password',)
        write_only_fields = ('password',)
```

How can I prevent DRF to return the created password in the response?

Comment: See if [this SO QA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18812732/dynamically-include-or-exclude-serializer-class-fields) can help you out

Answer (score 0):

Declare the password field explicitly like this and rest of the code will remain same:

```
password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)
```

Other method can be to delete the password from the to_representation method:

```
def to_representation(self, instance):
    ret = super(MySerializer, self).to_representation(instance)
    del ret['password']
    return ret
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use different serializers for creating a user and for showing the user's data. For example, you may inherit from the basic `UserSerializer` class and thus create something like `ReadOnlyUserSerializer`, where you completely remove the `password` field from the Meta.fields property.
The only thing you will need to do is to switch between these serializers properly in ViewSets or whatever you use to render the output.